# Rename a file to move the version number from the end to the beginning

Tags: linux, rename

How do I rename a file in linux and take the version # from the end and move it to the beginning. For example I have a file name:

```
Random text - text 1.1 (SD).mp3
```

to

```
1.1 Random text - text.mp3
```

Right now I can grab the version number but can't move it to the beginning, I have something like:

```
rename -n 's/(\d{1}\.\d{1}) \(SD\).mp3/$1.mp3/' *.mp3
```

which gives me

```
Random text - text 1.1.mp3
```

I tried to add a second expression group to match the beginning of the file so I can swap the beginning and the end but then nothing happens

Comment: I see a space in the regex of your rename command.  Is it supposed to be there, and if so should it be escaped with \?

Comment: @darenw: Spaces do not need to be escaped in regexes.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression should look like this:

```
rename -n 's/^(.*)(\d{1}\.\d{1})(.*)$/$2 $1$3/' *.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
's/^(.+?) (\d+\.\d+) \(SD\)/$2 $1/'
```

Or if you want to keep the `(SD)` part:

```
's/^(.+?) (\d+\.\d+) /$2 $1 /'
```